# Can't load file from another folder

Tags: reactjs

The project is totaly new ( created with `create-react-app` ) just like me in `react`. Red all the post about `babel` and `webpack`. Installed it, ejected it and everything I found. The error is:

```
Error in ./components/MyInfo.js
Module parse failed: /var/www/html/react/myfirstapp/components/MyInfo.js Unexpected token (5:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:8)
 @ ./src/index.js 13:14-45
```

If the `MyInfo.js` is in the same foldee as `index.js` it works fine. After moving it to `components` folder the error occured. MyInfo:

```
import React from "react"

function MyInfo() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Toma</h1>
            <p>My name is Toma</p>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyInfo
```

Index.js:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

import MyInfo from "../components/MyInfo"

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyInfo />,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Comment: Were you having the same issue before ejecting and modifying your webpack configuration? If you made changes to your webpack, you will likely need to detail them in the question.

Comment: I reverted the changes that I made. Still the same thing. Before all these steps the error was the same. At the moment that I moved the file to separate folder the error came.

Comment: Okay, can you confirm that your path is 100% correct? Is the folder `components/` at the same level as `index.js`? If it is, the path would be `import MyInfo from "./components/MyInfo"`.

Comment: `src` and `components` are in root directory. `index.js` is in src and `MyInfo.js` is in components. I think they are ok. I tried to changed the path just to check but then the error says that the file doesn't exist. So guess atleast the path is ok :D

Comment: Can you please create a new `create-react-app` application and without ejecting see if it works? Your code works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bbt5nx so it's likely an issue that happened with ejecting

Comment: I just moved the folder `components` to `src` folder and it works fine now. In the new project it says that this is the problem.